# How to fetch records with base interface for any child implemented class in jpa or hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have created a Base entity interface with getId() method and implemented into
entities for doing crud operations on all entity save is works and 
delete,update also work but retriving by id doesnt work i am not sure its 
possible or not if possible then suggest or any other way.

this is base interface for all entities and getId() overrides in each entity

```
public interface DemoEntity extends Serializable {
 public long getId();
 }
```

this is an user entity

```
public class User implements Serializable,DemoEntity {
 getter/setters
}

public class Subject implements Serializable,DemoEntity {
getter/setters
}
//this is modelmanager class for doing crud operations

 public class ModelManager {
 @Autowired 
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;
 @Transactional
 public void save(DemoEntity entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
 }
 @Transactional
 public DemoEntity getEntityById(long id) {
    DemoEntity de=em.find(DemoEntity.class, id);
    return de;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Autowired <-- is not necessary
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;
```

Your method would looks like better

```
 @Transactional
 public DemoEntity getEntityById(long id) {        
    return em.find(DemoEntity.class, id);
  }
```

and on the top of the class you need to put an annotation like `@Component @Repository`

And finally you did not say what kind of error you got

Comment: issue is in getEntityById() not working it gives error: Unable to locate persister: org.pack.DemoEntity",